# Unable to submit beta app to Windows phone store

Tags: windows-phone, marketplace, windows-phone-store

Recently I've experienced a strange behaviour of Windows phone store marketplace.

I tried to submit my app as a beta app but the option of Beta app is showing hide as in the picture attached.[image]

I'm unable to change radio button selection from "Public Store" to "Beta".

Comment: Just create a new beta app and you should be fine.  I generally have 1 app for the actual releases to the store, and another purely for beta testing.  I never try to switch from one to the other as I can just publish the xap to either app whenever I want.

Comment: ya, that's an alternative..
but i exclaimed why this happened..?
i want to know, is there anything i don't know about beta app publishing in WP store..?

Comment: I don't think you can change a published store app to beta.  Perhaps the other way round.  but either way it makes no difference as you can submit a beta anytime and very quickly, so you lose nothing!